# react-redux action to reducer relationship

Tags: react-redux

So I am learning React-Redux.  I am trying to find a way to load a value from the database first on load instead of just starting from 0. I have written an action that will hit an endpoint on my node file and pull from my mongo database.  This works. However the action never seems to reach the reducer to actually update the store.  Can someone explain to me the right way to make sure this action is store aware.

Here is the code for the action. Note the console.log with the number prints out what I want. I just never see the logs in the reducer that it was even ever reached.

```
export function setFooClicks(){
  console.log("in the set foo clicks action")
  var number = 0;
  //return function(dispatch){
    //console.log("in the return function")
    return axios.get('/clicks').then(result => {

      number = result.data

      console.log("The number of clicks is", number)
      //return number
      return{
        type: types.SETFOOCLICKS,
        totalFoo: result.data

      }

    }).catch((error) => {
      return console.log(error);
    })
  //} 


}
```

I am trying to grab it in the top level container at the moment so here is the code for that.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Foo from '../components/Foo'
import { incrementFoo, setFooClicks } from '../actions'



class FooContainer extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    setFooClicks();
  }
  render() {  

    return (
        <div>
      <Foo incrementFooAction={() => this.props.incrementFoo()} totalFoo={this.props.totalFoo}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    totalFoo: state.foo.totalFoo 
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { incrementFoo,setFooClicks })(FooContainer)
```

The normal incrementFoo action works but trying to add the setFooClicks action into the component as well doesn't.  Lastly here is the code to the reducer funciton.  All I did was add a case to the switch block.

```
export default function incrementFoo(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log("I am in the foo reducer")
  console.log(action.type)
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT:
        console.log(state.totalFoo);
      return {
        ...state,
        totalFoo: state.totalFoo + 1
      }
    case SETFOOCLICKS:
      console.log("in the SETFOOCLICKS reducer")
      return{
        ...state,
        totalFoo: action.totalFoo
      }  
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```